# How to calculate actual dollar values from the fibonacci extension on Trading View

Tags: trading, technical-analysis

Can someone tell me how to calculate these fibonacci extension values?

For example, this extension is from 300.50 to 89.29.

Now, when I look at the .786 or .618 values, I figured you just multiply .786 or .618 times 300.50 to get those values, which according to the extension is 255.30 and 219.81.

But, if you multiply .786 x 300.50 you get 236.19 and 300.50 x .618 = 185.71.

Can someone tell me how to get those values calculated by the extension?

Thanks.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fibonacci Retracements are created by first examining the distance between two points.
In your chart there is a line between 89.29 and 300.5.
The distance is solved for by subtracting the beginning point from the end point:
`300.5 – 89.28 = 211.21`

The distance (211.21) is then multiplied by the Fibonacci Ratios of 23.6%, 38.2%, 61.8%

For example take the first one 23.6:
`211.21 X .236 = 48.85`

Then you add back in your starting point, in this case 89.29:
`48.85 + 89.29 = 139.14`

and so on for the other ratios

I rounded these numbers to two decimal places for simplicity if you plug in actual values in a spreadsheet you can match what trading view comes up with.

Comment: When I look over your answer, I keep thinking to myself, why I didn't see that :) Anyways, thank you so much!

Comment: Thanks I had to look at that chart for a few to see what they were doing.